# ModelSim 10.1c fatal error

Tags: modelsim

I'm facing a big problem with `ModelSim 10.1c`.
I'm trying to simulate an UVM code but the following error has arising:

```
  UVM_INFO verilog_src/questa_uvm_pkg-1.2/src/questa_uvm_pkg.sv(215) @ 0: reporter [Questa UVM] QUESTA_UVM-1.2
# UVM_INFO verilog_src/questa_uvm_pkg-1.2/src/questa_uvm_pkg.sv(217) @ 0: reporter [Questa UVM]  questa_uvm::init(+struct)
# UVM_INFO @ 0: reporter [RNTST] Running test ...
# ** Fatal: vl_unpack_regbit: Cannot handle type.
```

Has someone face this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old version of Modelsim and most likely the is a problem with your code that triggered a problem with Modelsim. Since the simulation is already running, you show be able to narrow down the construct causing the fatal error.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately Modelsim does not support the UVM, you need at least Questa Prime. Modelsim only supports the so called SystemVerilog for Design which lacks the required Verification constructs likes bins, covergroup, rand, etc.

Comment: Modelsim does support the UVM, it just that user's code cannot have and of the verification constructs like randomize() covergroups and assertions.

Comment: That is silly down vote,  as a Mentor Verification Technologist you should know the correct answer is still Modelsim *does not* support the UVM. Sure you can try to unravel constraints, mess around with rand, change assertions to OVL (assuming PE), change bins to counters, etc but in the end you might as well write your own verification framework. I challenge anybody to take some UVM IP and run it on Modelsim,  it is simply not a realistic task. For small hello world programs you might be OK but for anything else, don't bother, life is too short.

Comment: @HDTLab, as someone who works for Mentor, I do know that there are many people using the Student and Altera versions of Modelsim with the UVM library, and have come up with clever ways of getting around the lack of a constraint solver by using $urandom. True, you are not going to get large commercial designs through Modelsim, but all of the class based object-oriented features are there to build a UVM compliant testbench,

Comment: Thanks to all for your answer, as a conclusing, should i continue with modelsim or switch to questa prime,

Finally what is the tool that should fully suport UVM, is it aldec riviera?

Comment: Hi Saketa, if you can switch to Questa Prime then I would strongly recommend you do that. Both Riviera Pro and Questa Prime fully supports the UVM (and SV for Verification) with all the bells and whistles you need to write and debug your code.  Good luck.